# regex to find a word before and after a specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that gives me the word before and after a specific word, included the search word itself.

Like: "*This is some dummy text to find a word*" should give me a string of "dummy **text** to" when **text** is my search word.

Another question, it's possible that the string provided will contain more then once the search word so I must be able to retrieve all matches in that string with C#.

Like "*This is some dummy text to find a word in a string full with text and words*"
Should return:

- "dummy **text** to"
- "with **text** and"

**EDIT:**
Actually I should have all the matches returned that contain the search word. 
A few examples:
Text is too read. -> Text is

Read my text. -> my text

This is a text-field example -> a text-field example

Comment: And what if the string is "I need to text text to dummy"? Should it return "to text text" and "text text to"?

Comment: indeed, just the word before and after my search word, whatever it may be :)

Comment: What about `"one text two text three"`? i.e. Do you need to handle overlapping matches?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you want to *grab all the content from the space before first word to the space after the word* use:

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?
```

A simple tests:

```
string input = @"
    This is some dummy text to find a word in a string full with text and words
    Text is too read
    Read my text.
    This is a text-field example
    this is some dummy la@text.be to read";

var matches = Regex.Matches(
    input,
    @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

the matches are:

```
dummy text to
with text and
Text is
my text.
a text-field example
dummy la@text.be to
```

Comment: Looks good! But what if there are other chars before or after the word? Like @ or . or something something. Is it possible to grab all the content from the space before first word to the space after the word? So "this is some dummy la@text.be to read" would" still result in "dummy la@text.be to" but this way all other chars and words are included. Sry for being suchs a pain. Or must I solve this without regex?

Comment: i want whole string before Text and between Text..., how can i do it

Comment: @Alex can you check this Question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131758/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 7):

```
//I prefer this style for readability

string pattern = @"(?<before>\w+) text (?<after>\w+)";
string input = "larry text bob fred text ginger fred text barney";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("before:" + matches[i].Groups["before"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("after:" + matches[i].Groups["after"].ToString());
} 

/* Output:
before:larry
after:bob
before:fred
after:ginger
before:fred
after:barney
*/
```

Comment: Nice, is there a easy way to control the number of words before / after to match. Lets say I want 3 words and 2 after?

Answer (score 2):

```
/[A-Za-z'-]+ text [A-Za-z'-]+/
```

Should work in most cases, including hyphenated and compound words.

Comment: thx, that was fast. Can you show me the C# line to use this regex? Thx!

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx#Y6404) have a very thorough example of how to use regular expressions in C# which should be very useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-z]+) text ([A-z]+)
```

would do nicely

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than you think. You need `[A-Za-z]` at least (which will still fail on words containing non-ASCII characters...).

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z]+\stext\s[a-zA-Z]+

I believe this will work nicely