# Matching words after a word

Tags: c#, regex, .net-2.0, cpu-word, match

I'm wondering, is it possible to use regex to match a word after a specific word? For example, suppose you have a string like this:

```
test abcde  
dummy test fghij
```

Would it be possible to obtain a string array which contains the words after test (abcde and fghij)? If so, can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
(?:test\s)(?<word>\b\S+\b)
```

**Explanation**

```
(?:test\s)       matches "test" with a trailing blank, but does not include it in the capture
(?<word>\b\S+\b) matches a word with any character except a whitespace. It will be stored in a group called "word".
```

Here is a little example how to use it:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:test\s)(?<word>\b\S+\b)");
var matchCollection = regex.Matches("test abcde   dummy test fghij ");

foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(match.Groups["word"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason the MatchCollection matches the correct word, but matches the word "test" as well. Why is this?

Comment: Also, how would you get the word before test in this case?

Comment: Also, how do I grab the word before "test"?

Comment: @david: I changed my answer, so you can get only the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use RegEx, but a simple `yourString.Split(' ');`.

Then, you can :

```
var strings = yourString.Split(' ');

var afterTest = strings.Skip(strings.IndexOf("test"))
```

It will be faster, simpler and more secure.

Also read [Jeff Atwood's entry about regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: When I tested it, it says Skip is not a valid method. Does it not exist in NET 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the Net-2.0 tag in your question. It's a method available from the V3.0 version

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookbehind with the pattern `(?<=test).+`.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("test abcd\ndummy test fghij", @"(?<=test).+");
```

Comment: but this matches more than one word after "test" like OP wants it to be. If you change it to `(?<=test)\b.+\b` it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList aWrods = new ArrayList();

string[] sArr = yourString.Split(' ');
for (int i=0; i<sArr.Count()-1; i++)
    if (sArr[i] == "test")
        aWords.Add(sArr[i+1]);
```

Comment: The code is a bit flawed (there is no Count() for string array, you are splitting the text by whitespace char only and not separate lines) but I get the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832693/regex-to-find-a-word-before-and-after-a-specific-word)

If you want to *grab all the content from the space before first word to the space after the word* use:

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?
```

A simple tests:

```
string input = @"
    This is some dummy text to find a word in a string full with text and words
    Text is too read
    Read my text.
    This is a text-field example
    this is some dummy la@text.be to read";

var matches = Regex.Matches(
    input,
    @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

the matches are:

```
dummy text to
with text and
Text is
my text.
a text-field example
dummy la@text.be to
```