# Regex finding word/two words before/after specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find a word in html, also want to get the words before and after the word. 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832693/regex-to-find-a-word-before-and-after-a-specific-word) question given a answer by use (?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?  and using c#. But does not work on javascript.  Javascript looks like it doesn't support `?:`?
Any ideas?

For example

> Woobox, a two-year old social marketing platform, recently added support for Apple’s Passbook in its coupons app. The integration lets businesses create Passbook coupons using its system, and can even require customers to perform some sort of social action before gaining access to the coupon. For example, they may have to “like” the brand on Facebook or follow them on Twitter. But the company has also just added another feature which could really spur Passbook adoption at the small business level: support for Passbook coupons over SMS.

When I search 'coupon' ,  I should get four result:  'its coupons app',  'Passbook coupons using', 'the coupon.', 'Passbook coupons over'

Comment: JavaScript does support `(?:...)` - where's your problem exactly?

Comment: Please put the whole question in this question.  Don't make us go to another question to find out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?
```

doesn't work in JavaScript, you're using it wrong (or you need to define what you mean by "work"). Most likely you're not using the correct syntax to construct a regex:

```
var myregexp = /(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?/;
```

or how to find a match in a string:

```
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[0];
}
```

Comment: my code works fine to use other regexp, but can not get error result by use this regex.  When search 'or' but get 'world'

Comment: I don't understand what you've written there. I suspect you want to use word boundaries (search for `\bor\b` instead of `or`).

Comment: I search 'coupon', it working fine, can get result like 'the coupon' but also can get 'coupons' ,  so I add '\b' before and after the searching word, then only can get 'coupon' , do not include the words around 'coupon'.

Comment: @atu0830: This is not helping. What you're writing is incoherent and incomplete. Please edit your question with several examples of what text you have, which parts you do or don't want to match, what regex you're using for this, and what that regex is not doing as you would have expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript *does* support the [non-matching group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) syntax `(?:…)`. It even supports [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which could be useful for your task, only it does not support lookbehind.

Comment: should I escape  '?:' like '\\?:'

Comment: No, only if you wanted to match a question mark and a colon