# Get the word before and after a certain word?

Tags: php, regex

> The children likes to watch the cartoon Tom **and** Jerry but not Dora the Explorer!

I want to get the first and last word after "and" so the above would have an output of: Tom and Jerry

I have considered using the explode function using and as a delimiter but would get everything to the left and right of and.

```
  $string="The children likes to watch the cartoon Tom and Jerry but not Dora the Explorer!";

  list($left,$right)=explode('and',$string);

  echo $left; //The children likes to watch the cartoon Tom
  echo $right; //Jerry but not Dora the Explorer!
```

I thought I found a [solution but it was written for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832693/regex-to-find-a-word-before-and-after-a-specific-word).

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried and doesn't work?

Comment: The regular expression is the same in PHP as in C#. Why doesn't that answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can you this expression
//pass your string and match in this expression

```
$string="The children likes to watch the cartoon Tom and Jerry but not Dora the Explorer!";//this is your string
$find="and";//word to match
preg_match("!(\S+)\s*$find\s*(\S+)!i", $string, $match);
echo $before = $match[1];
echo $after = $match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just explode the $left and $right into arrays using space as delimeter, or something along those lines

```
$arrayLeft = explode(' ', $left);
$arrayRight = explode(' ', $right);
```

then do a count array for the left to get the last word

```
$countArray = count($arrayLeft);
$countArray--;//or whatever syntax to make it minus 1
```

then you have

```
$arrayLeft[$countArray]// for Tom
$arrayRight[0]// for jerry
```